# StreamingQueryException in Spark kafka Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am working on Kafka Spark streaming using Java, when i do writeStream() to console, I am getting below error.

```
18/06/11 22:26:59 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 38e7ebe2-41bb-40e7-83fa-6c14aad5e519, runId = b09f10fd-c594-424b-ba7a-42b2747ed7fd] terminated with error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected e.g. {"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}}, got from-beginning. Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Expected e.g. {"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}}, got from-beginning. === Streaming Query === Identifier: [id = 38e7ebe2-41bb-40e7-83fa-6c14aad5e519, runId = b09f10fd-c594-424b-ba7a-42b2747ed7fd]
```

i tried extending SparkQueryException, but of no use. Why is this ocuring and how can I fix this.